# Translate no angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material

Estou usando o i18n no angular, como imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No app.component.ts está assim:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public translate : any;
  constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(["pt", "en"]);
    translate.setDefaultLang("pt");
    const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    translate.use(browserLang.match(/pt|en/) ? browserLang : "pt");
  }
}
```

Para chamar o que está descrito no in8, faço assim no html:
`<span>{{ 'SISTEMA' | translate }} {{ 'NOME_DO_SISTEMA' | translate }}</span>`

No json do inglês está assim:

```
{
  "NOME_DO_SISTEMA": "from medical clinic",
}
```

No json do português está assim:

```
{
  "NOME_DO_SISTEMA": "de clinica médica",
}
```

Preciso se o usuário mudar a linguagem, muda o arquivo de acordo com a linguagem definida.

Fiz assim:

```
          <option *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" [value]="lang" [selected]="lang === translate.currentLang">

            {{ lang }}</option>

        </select>
```

Mas tem erro conforme imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando **@ngx-translate/http-loader**.

O que pode ser ?

Answer (score 1):

Se o translate não for adicionado ao módulos não tem nem como o serviço iniciar ou reconhece-lo, então no app.modules adicione:

```
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';

...

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot()
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Deve-se usar o `TranslateModule.forRoot()`, é como se fosse um "boot", mas claro que este é o caso de uso para "tudo", para usar, você também pode usar para [`SharedModule`](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) que não será compartilhado com tudo, mas será compartilhado aonde for "chamado", como componentes ou "pipes", para adicionar ao `SharedModule` crie um módulo com um nome qualquer e adicione isto (é apenas um exemplo):

```
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Ou pode usar o LazyLoadModule, como descrito no repositório: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#lazy-loaded-modules

Comment: Acredito que sim, vou colocar o código